# conditional 'from' in mongodb lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to lookup in multiple collections, based on a specific field.
for example if field `type` equals to `1`, lookup the collection from `Admin` and if type equals to `2`, lookup from `Client`.I know the following query is incorrect, but i just want to show what i mean.

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {

        "$lookup":{
            "localField":"ID",
            "from":{"$cond": { if: { "type":1 } ,then: "Admin", else: "Client"} },
            "foreignField":"ID",
            "as":"newUser"
        },
        {
        "$unwind":"$newUser"
        }

    }])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `type` is document field or your function variable? If it is document field then it is not possible to conditionally put the `from` expression in `$lookup` and if it's variable then use normal javascript `if else`.

Comment: `type` is document field. how to use js `if else`  inside lookup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, you cant, the only solution is to use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) and have 2 separated pipelines.

As you probably imagine this is not a great solution as it wastes resources on the redundant pipeline.

I'm not sure if you can involve some code but if you can it is your best option.

$facet pipeline draft:

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {
       $facet: {
          user: [
           {
            "$lookup":{
                "localField":"ID",
                "from":Client,
                "foreignField":"ID",
                "as":"newUser"
             },
           },
           {
              "$unwind":"$newUser"
           }],
          admin: [
            {
            "$lookup":{
                "localField":"ID",
                "from":Admin,
                "foreignField":"ID",
                "as":"newUser"
              },
           },
           {
              "$unwind":"$newUser"
           }],
       }
    },
    {
       $match: {
            use "correct" user here..
       }
    }
])
```

Comment: i get this error : `elements of arrays in $facet spec must be non-empty objects, user argument contained an element of type string: 0: '$lookup'`

Comment: i used `$match` inside the pipeline and it worked.thanks.